Club sets and elementary substructures
Given any set $X$, we say $C\subseteq\mathcal{P}(X)$ is club when there is $F:X^{<\omega}\to X$ so that for every non-empty $z\subseteq X$, $z\in C$ if and only if $F[z^{<\omega}]\subseteq z$. Now if $L$ is a countable language and $M=(X,...)$ is a structure in $L$, then via an encoding $F$ of a fixed list of Skolem functions on $X$, we can see that the closure points under $F$ are all universes for some elementary substructure of $M$. This tells us that the set $$\{z\subseteq X:M\restriction z\prec M\}$$ contains a club. But conversely, it need not be true that every elementary substructure of $M$ is closed under Skolem functions. My question is: is there an explicit counterexample for which this set cannot possibly be club?

Maybe $\mathbb{Q}$?

@MathieuRundström How can I see that the elementary substructures for $\mathbb{Q}$ are not club?

@MathieuRundström If you mean $\mathbb{Q}$ with its field structure, then this set would be the singleton ${\mathbb{Q}}$; consider a bijection $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{Q}$ and let $F(x_0,...,x_n)=f(n)$. Then trivially the only non-empty set closed under $F$ is $\mathbb{Q}$ itself

For $F\colon X^{<\omega}\to X$, let $C_F = \{Z\subseteq X\mid F[Z^{<\omega}]\subseteq Z\}$. Then for every $Y\subseteq X$, there is a smallest $Z\in C_F$ containing $Y$, namely the closure of $Y$ under $F$. In particular, $C_F$ contains a smallest element, the closure of $\varnothing$ under $F$.
This is not true in general for the set of elementary substructures of a fixed structure $M$. For example, taking $M$ to be $(\mathbb{Q},<)$, $M$ has no smallest elementary substructure, and there is no smallest elementary substructure of $M$ containing $\mathbb{Z}$. So $\{Z\subseteq \mathbb{Q}\mid Z\preceq \mathbb{Q}\}$ is not a club in your sense.

However, your definition of club is not the standard one! Usually, for a fixed uncountable regular cardinal $\kappa$ and a set $X$ with $|X|\geq \kappa$, we say that a set $C\subseteq \mathcal{P}_\kappa(X) = \{Z\subseteq X\mid |Z|<\kappa\}$ is a club if it is:

Closed: For any chain $(Z_\beta)_{\beta<\alpha}$ with $\alpha<\kappa$ in $C$, $\bigcup_{\beta<\alpha} Z_\beta\in C$.
Unbounded: For any $Y\in \mathcal{P}_\kappa(X)$, there is some $Z\in C$ with $Y\subseteq Z$.

A reference is Jech's Set Theory, p. 100.
This is weaker than your definition (after restricting to $\mathcal{P}_\kappa(X)$): For any $F\colon X^{<\omega}\to X$, $C_F = \{Z\in \mathcal{P}_\kappa(X)\mid F[Z^{<\omega}]\subseteq Z\}$ is a club.
But with the standard definition, if $M$ is an $L$-structure with $|M|\geq \kappa>|L|$, the set of elementary substructures of $M$ of cardinality $<\kappa$ is always a club.

Thank you for your response! This definition that I adapt comes from Larson's The Stationary Tower. The definition from Jech also seems reasonable, but for the purposes of generic embeddings I think this difference is not too substantial.
